# accessing another systems database?

Tags: java, mysql

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'dexterlabs06' (using password: YES)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:920)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4000)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1285)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2186)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:787)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>       at Testloginserv.doPost(Testloginserv.java:41)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 1):

On the database, grant privileges for your system and it should work.
Like `your_user_name@'192.192.192.192'`

Have a look at this [tutorial on granting privileges in MySQL](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3a+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv)

Comment: how can i do that please tell me

Comment: Grant all privilages on *.* to 'root'@'192.168.3.7' identified by 'root; i tried this but not working

Comment: do i need to create any user in my database

Comment: in the above grant statement i have given user name of mysql and password

Comment: if user is not created then you need to create a user first then grant privileges

Comment: other database and do i need to run mysql as admin for doing this

Comment: yes you should run it as admin otherwise changes will not take effect

Comment: how can i run mysql as admin,do i need to uninstall and reinstall that as admin

Comment: if your are using windows based OS, right click on your MySQL icon and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: otherwise click on `Start` menu and locate your `MySQL` program and then right click it.

Comment: actually what my requirement is i have to insert login details of user  into other sytems mysql database from my system using login page.for this i have created a jsp login page and retrieved the data from login page to servlte then i tied to connect to other system database to insert data

Comment: please post it in your question, we can't go long on making comments.